# Custom Authentication in Google Cloud Mobile Backend Starter in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints, facebook-authentication

Can we implement custom authentication in Mobile Backend Starter? Instead of google account, I want users to login using facebook account. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? If we could log in with other providers I'd be very interested.

Comment: Agreed. Would be nice to see an answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes it's possible to implement other OAuth2 authorizations like Facebook, LinkedIn or Twitter.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365858/google-cloud-endpoints-and-users-authentication) an aswer with code examples how to achieve this.

In short you have to implement your own `Authenticator` and update `@Api` annotation to take the custom authenticator into account.

```
@Api(name = "example", authenticators = { CustomAuthenticator.class })
```

More about custom authenticators can be found in [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/javadoc/com/google/api/server/spi/config/Authenticator.html).

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any official support/docs/online tutorials/experiments to do this yet unfortunately. Will be on the lookout since I am also rolling in one MBS instance.
Well there is the OPEN mode which allows unauthenticated requests.