# How to implement OAuth 2.0 in Google Cloud Endpoint - Java

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

I am looking for Oauth 2.0 implementation to Google Endpoint project developed in Java. Client will be web and Android.
Kindly suggest how to implement it. I have searched lot of google docs. Each doc details something but I couldn't connect dots basically. Anyone has implemented OAuth 2.0 in Google Endpoint ?

Comment: There is a step by step guide for OAuth with Google here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth

Comment: There's also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365858/google-cloud-endpoints-and-users-authentication if you want more than just Google OAuth.

Comment: @konqi first of all thanks for ur inputs. I have gone through the first link already. I have made changes also for one of my endpoint method with user object. When I tried to test it from Google API explorer, I am getting user object as null always. Do you know how to test authentication from Google API explorer?

Comment: @konqi, Do we need to write a J2EE Filter to validate the OAuth access token? or App Engine is having some implemetation(we just need to enable it). I am bit confused, how to enable OAuth 2.0 for my Enpoint APIs.

Comment: @Karthikaiselvan: the [first link provided above](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth) has steps which explain what is necessary to get a null or non-null User object. I suggest you re-read the relevant doc and review your code to determine why the User object is appearing as `null`.

Comment: @Nick, Thank you anyway!. I have resolved it. Actually, Google Cloud Endpoint has its own implementation (handled internally) to verify access token from request header and injects User object into endpoint methods. So, once I started passing valid access token using Postman client using OAuth 2.0 security mode, it has started giving valid User object.

Comment: @Karthikaiselvan that's great news! Would you mind posting that as a self-answer, possibly including an example (destroy or change the token somehow) HTTP request header as your server sees it, or as your browser sees it in the developer tools network tab?

Comment: @Nick Sorry for late update. Here is the doc link for the step by step explanation. https://docs.google.com/document/d/16CJwGnqqZMx7Gk3i3X9q81ptcVl7pWqorAkBEp08u58/edit?usp=sharing